# Angular - switch to different backends

Tags: angular, spring, netflix-zuul

I have an angular app that is supposed to connect to different backends depending on the environment it is deployed to. There is a local, 3 integration and one prod env. The problem is that I can change angular environment during build process (ng build INT..), but the build-job for integration on jenkins does not know on which server it is going to be deployed. Int1, Int2 or Int3.

I tried zuul, but have no idea how to switch the server backend after building the angular app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know your server name/URL during build time, another solution is to replace the Angular environment's property by a placeholder:

```
// environment.prod.ts
// ...
  backendUrl: '%BACKEND_URL%'
// ...
```

This will end up bundled in the `main.js` file. Then, at deployment time (when actually copying the Angular files) you could run a script on the machine that replace the placeholder with the actual server URL, using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's~%BACKEND_URL%~http://backend.server.org/api~g' main.js
```